# VS Code has issues with Pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

My environment: Mac, Python 3.9, venv.

This is the file I want to lint (editor isn't showing linting).
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
fc = 1
```

Running the linter in command line returns the expected:
[image]

I already checked various SO entries and applied following proposed solutions

1. In vscode I enabled linting, selected pylint as linter and run
2. I disabled the minimal checkers. My .vscode/settings.json:

   ```
   {
   "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
   "python.linting.enabled": true,
   "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
   "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python"
   }
   ```
3. Created a `.pylintrc` with `pylint --generate-rcfile -encoding utf8 > ~/.pylintrc`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check Output console tab? Various plugins post error messages there. There are multiple sub-consoles so you might need to poke around a bit.

Comment: checked all tabs, no linting related output. Just `[INFO 11:50:55.902] autoDocstring was activated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, it is recommended that you check the following two files:

1. Please check whether the settings file "`settings.json`" contains `"python.linting.pylintArgs": [],` related settings.

   In addition to the "`.vscode/settings.json`" you provided, we should also pay attention to check whether the global setting "`User/settings.json`" contains the above settings, it will turn off the Pylint information if the content is set.

   for example: `"python.linting.pylintArgs":[ "----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml" ]` This has closed content, so it will close Pylint information. Please comment out this setting.
2. Since you created the file "`.pylintrc`", please check whether the file contains like

> ```
> disable=
>      C0114, # missing-module-docstring
>      C0103, # invalid-name"
> ```

related settings, it will turn off specific Pylint notifications.

Effect:

[image]

The content of my "`.vscode/settings.json`" is basically the same as yours. The following is the content of my "`User/settings.json`":

```
{
  
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
  "python.linting.enabled": true, 
  "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
  
       
}
```

Comment: Adding `"python.linting.pylintArgs": []` to `.vscode/settings.json` resolved the issue. many thanks for the valuable hint

Comment: I also checked my User `settings.json` where I found `"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile",
        "${workspaceFolder}/backend/.pylintrc"
    ]`. Obvously this caused the issue. Can I safely remove what's inside the brackets?

Comment: @zinyosrim  -Yes, this is exactly what is suggested in my answer (1.). Please comment out this setting. It will turn off Pylint information if the content is set, and it is also available if the content of this setting is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you disabled `Minimal checkers` in your config file, but it works for me with VScode GUI support so let's give it a try:

Config -  When I use pylint as the Linter and `Minimal checkers` is disabled:
[image]

Result - Global variable in lowerCase is generating a message.
[image]

**NOTE: Please make sure that you are using Pylint as linter (like in the first image attached).**

Comment: my GUI settings are the same as yours so far

Comment: Can you check if you see anything Output tab? Sounds like for the question author the plugin is not somehow activated or not running.

Comment: My output shows the pylint command and output, but somehow it is not running on the author environment. :/